# iOS Certificate Generation Error: Disc Quota Exceeded

Tags: ios, macos, certificate, development-environment

I am trying to generate an iOS Development Certificate. After I select the `.certSigningRequest` file from my desktop and click on `Generate`, I get the following error:

`Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Disc quota exceeded`

Why is this happening and how can I generate my certificate?

Comment: It's been bad for a few days now. Painful.

Comment: The problem seems to be solved, I generated the certificate. Unfortunately, someone has deleted all helpful answers and the one that is still there is pretty bad, so I cannot accept it.

Comment: I still have the same error, hopefully it's indeed just a server error that will resolve itself.

Comment: Seems to be server related, no local errors on your machine! Check http://fixingxcode.tumblr.com/post/50576778169/processing-of-multipart-form-data-request-failed-disc

Comment: Its still broken ... go apple ...

Comment: The error still appears sometimes but with some more time and tries, you should be able to generate your certificates.

Comment: I am getting this problem on June 2nd, 2013. Feels like Apple is only putting bandaids on their space issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: I didn't knew that it is an Apple issue at the point of time when I posted the question. I was thinking that I am doing something wrong and wanted to know what. This is also pretty clear from the question and seems that it has interested other people as well. I find it really pity that in the last months questions are closed just like that. Not that I care for this particular question, I found the answer a long time ago. But it is one of the main reasons for me not using so much SO now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the Apple server and I, as user, am not able to do anything for solving it. From time to time, certificates can be generated, so keep trying. Unfortunately, the problem has not been solved by Apple yet, so this error appears quite frequently.

Answer (score -4):

1.) Create your Apple developer account and join the iOS Developer Program. It will cost you $99/year and it allows you to test your apps on a device and distribute your apps in the app store. You can go here to register.

http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

2.) Now that you are registered the first thing we need to do is generate a Certificate Signing Request. We can do this in KeyChain Access on our mac. It’s in the Utilities folder under Applications.

3.) After you have opened up Keychain Access go to Preferences.
Go to the Certificates tab and make sure “Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP)” and “Certificate Revocation List (CRL)” are both set to Off.
Close the Preferences window and choose “Keychain Access -> Certificate Assistant -> Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority”.

4.) Enter the “User Email Address” and “Common Name” that you submitted when you registered as an iOS developer. “CA Email Address” is not required.

Select “Saved to disk” and “Let me specify key pair information”.

Click continue.

5.) Specify a file name and a place to save the CSR. Here I’m just using the default name and saving it to the desktop.

6.) Select 2048 bits for the Key Size, and RSA for the Algorithm.
Click continue.

7.) The CSR has now been created and saved to your desktop.
You can now close Keychain Access.

8.) Now that we have the CSR created it’s time to submit it. We do this in the iOS Provisioning Portal at http://developer.apple.com/. You won’t be able to see or access the provisioning portal until you are registered as an iOS developer and logged in.

9.) After going to the provisioning portal select Certificates on the left side.

10.) If you don’t have the WWDR installed download it and install it. After you download it, just double click it and Keychain will install it for you. Then it should show up in the certificates category.

11.) After you have the WWDR certificate installed it’s time to request the main certificate. Click the “Request Certificate” button.

You’ll see a screen with instructions not unlike what you have ready here. How about that? Go to the bottom and click browse, then navigate to your CSR on your local machine.
After selecting your file click Open, then click Submit on the next screen.

12.) After hitting submit your request shows up in the Signing Requests section.
Because of the way our team is set up here at work I am then able to go and approve the request. This may be different with an individual account or a different team setup.

13.) After being approved, your certificate will show up under Current Development Certificates.
Click the download button to download it to your mac.
After it’s downloaded double click the file to install it in Keychain Access. Actually after double clicking, Keychain does all the work and it will just show up in your certificates.

14.) If you open Xcode and go to the Organizer window you should now see the new certificate there also.
To build with the new certificate you can either select the app under Targets.And do Get Info on it (command i).Or you can to Project > Edit Project Settings
Either way will open up the project info window and from there go to the Build tab and scroll down to the Code Signing section and select the new certificate for Code Signing Identity.

15.) That’s it. You now have your new certificate installed and selected, you can connect your device and click Build and Run.

Comment: Long answer with no relation to my question. I hope, @Deepesh is right and it is just a server issue.

Comment: You were asking "how to generate your certificate" this is a step by step